# referencing multiple mixins not picking the correct property values

Tags: variables, less, mixins

I have the following 2 mixins with different names in the same scope and defining the same variables - `@width` and `@height`:

```
.myMixin1 {
    @width:  100%;
    @height: 400px;  
}

.myMixin2 {
    @width:  75%;
    @height: 200px;
}
```

I reference both the above mixins from within the same style rule:

```
.myClass {
    .myMixin1;
    .myMixin2;
    width: @width;
    height: @height;
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.myClass {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

instead of

```
.myClass {
    width: 75%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

My question is:

Since `.myMixin2` is referenced last, shouldn't the class pick up the property values from this mixin?

Answer (score 1):

**I figured this out:**

Variables are not copied if the caller of the mixins contains variables with the same name defined by another mixin call. [LESS Docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature)

After `.myMixin1` is called, the caller already contains the variables @width and @height. Hence, a reference to `.myMixin2` does not copy over the variables with the same name.